# How to make cross shaped pattern corresponding with user input in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

How can I make this pattern ?

you'll see there is a cross pattern below (printed in space)

```
  ********


 * ****** *


 ** **** **


 *** ** ***


 ****  ****


 ****  ****


 *** ** ***


 ** **** **


 * ****** *


  ********
```

Here's what I've tried. I put the user input value with 10 for testing purpose.

```
uses crt;
var a,b,n,space1,space2 : integer;
begin
clrscr;
n:= 10;

space1:=1;
space2:=n;
for a:=1 to n do
 begin
 for b:=1 to n do
 begin

    if(b=space1) OR (b=space2-1) then
    begin
      write(' ');
      space1:=space1+1;
      space2:=space2-1;
    end else
     write('*');
end;

writeln;

end;
readkey;
```

I'm having trouble to print the space character.

I think the problem is in the if condition.

What's the best condition for this situation?

Comment: Normally we would expect you to show us what you have tried so far

Comment: sorry, I'll post my code in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is

```
StringOfChar(c: char, i: SizeInt): AnsiString
```

Example: Create 5 *

```
  var s: string;
  ..
  s := StringOfChar('*', 5);
  ..
```

For further help you should provide some example code with your work.

One way would be:

```
uses crt;
var a,b,n,space1,space2 : integer;
  s: string;
begin
  clrscr;
  n:= 10;

  // first half of cross
  for a:=0 to n div 2 -1 do begin
    s := StringOfChar('*', n-2);
    Insert(' ', s, a+1); // first space 
    Insert(' ', s, n-a); // last space
    writeln(s);
  end;

  // second half of cross    
  for a:= (n div 2 -1) downto 0 do begin
    s := StringOfChar('*', n-2);
    Insert(' ', s, a+1); // first space
    Insert(' ', s, n-a); // last space
    writeln(s);
  end;

  writeln;
  readkey;
end.
```

You can solve this problem also with just one loop.
I leave it to you as a learning exercise :-)

Comment: @Widy Graycloud changed my example. Feel free to ask questions if something isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your "if" to the following:

```
if (a = b) or (b = N - a + 1) then
    write(' ')
else
    write('*');
```